# Finding the inverse of linear transformation using matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, linear-transformations

Assuming I have a linear transformation represented by a matrix with respect to some random bases, how could I find the inverse of the transformation using the matrix representation?

I know I should find the inverse matrix but from there on, I have no clue what to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no "from there on": once you have the inverse matrix, assuming it exists at all, you've finished.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I was not clear enough. I need to work out the formula for the inverse if it is possible.
EDIT: I know how to find the inverse using usual method. I'm just curious if there's another method.
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: What are you considering as the "usual method" for finding an inverse ? There are at least two, through the cofactor matrix (mainly theoretical), or by inversing a system (main hand method).

Comment: I'm not sure how you say it in English. It is similar to finding inverse of a function.
For an example, f(x)=2x+5, then x=(f(x)-5)/2 and by swapping x and f(x) you get the inverse.

Answer (score 3):

Let $T$ be an invertible linear transformation from an $n$-dimensional vector space to another, $A$ its $(n \times n)$ matrix, $\mathcal B = \{\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n\}$ a basis for the domain, $\mathcal B' = \{\beta_1, \dots, \beta_n\}$ a basis for the co-domain, and $\beta = y_1\beta_1 + \cdots + y_n\beta_n$ a vector in the co-domain.

The inverse of $T, T^{-1},$ is related to $A^{-1}$ by $\left[T^{-1}\beta \right]_{\mathcal B} = A^{-1}[\beta]_{\mathcal B'},$ where $[ \cdot ]_{\mathcal B}$ denotes the coordinate matrix relative to the ordered basis $\mathcal B.$  Then with $A_{ij}^{-1}$ representing the $ij$ entry of $A^{-1},$ we compute
$$\begin{align}
\left[T^{-1}\beta \right]_{\mathcal B} & = A^{-1}[\beta]_{\mathcal B'}\\\\
& = A^{-1}[y_1\beta_1 + \cdots + y_n\beta_n]_{\mathcal B'}\\\\
& = A^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\ \vdots\\ y_n\end{bmatrix}\\\\
& = \begin{bmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^nA_{1i}^{-1}y_i\\ \vdots\\ \sum_{i=1}^nA_{ni}^{-1}y_i\end{bmatrix};\\\\
T^{-1}\beta & = \alpha_1 \sum_{i=1}^nA_{1i}^{-1}y_i + \cdots + \alpha_n \sum_{i=1}^nA_{ni}^{-1}y_i.\end{align}$$

If you are satisfied having your inverse in terms of $\mathcal B,$ we are done.

If, however, you want the inverse in terms of the standard ordered basis, express each $\alpha_i$ in terms of the standard basis, and group the terms in the last expression above by the elements of the standard basis.

For an example, see my answer to [Find linear transformation given its matrix representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2108758/find-linear-transformation-given-its-matrix-representation/2956788#2956788).  The procedure there is the same as that of obtaining $T^{-1}$ from $A^{-1}.$